Is there a tool to visualize the connections between specified authors?
Is there a tool that, provided a list of authors, visualizes the connections between these authors, if any?
Or at least a tool to  to visualize the academic citation network around several researchers (not one like in a similar question) at once in the same map/graph?

This probably isn't an "Academia" question -- in essence, all you need is a tool that visualizes a graph. I would start with the "graphviz" tool.

This is an Academia question, because this one https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86509/is-there-a-tool-to-visualize-the-academic-citation-network-around-a-researcher is.
